# mod_rewrite {QUERY_STRING}

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm sure that's been asked zillions times but i can't get it to work,
i'm trying to rewrite a url with querystring, my url is for example:

```
http://example.com/articles/index.php?keyword=book
```

and i want to be accessible from

```
http://example.com/articles/keyword/book/
```

I google it and i didn't have any luck, 
am i on the right track? i got this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^keyword=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/articles/index.php$         /articles/keyword/$1          [NC,L,R=301]
```

**UPDATE**

this is working fine

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*/(\w+)\b$ /articles/index.php?keyword=$1
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/keyword/(.*)/?$ index.php?keyword=$1
```

<sub>If not, please tell me ;)</sub>

Comment: What's the problem? What Apache gives? What's in the error logs?

Comment: that finally worked for me, RewriteRule ^.*/(\w+)\b$ /articles/index.php?keyword=$1